# how to add a class div on drupal 7 webform element?

Tags: forms, webforms

webform generated each form component in this structure

```
<div>
  <label></label>
  <input></input>
</div>
```

I like to add a div class on each input element

```
<div>
  <label></label>
  <div class="xxxx"><input></input></div>
</div>
```

I looked into the form alter to alter form element with `#field_prefix` and `#field_suffix`

```
$form['submitted']['chinese_name']['#field_prefix'] = '<div class="abc">';
$form['submitted']['chinese_name']['#field_suffix'] = '</div>';
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the incorrect keyword, the correct way to add a prefix to the webform field is:

```
$form['submitted']['chinese_name']['#prefix'] = '<div class="abc">';
$form['submitted']['chinese_name']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix and suffix will add wrapper element to whole form element, to add class to certain fields you can next thing.

For textfield you can do next find, go to `includes/form.inc` and find function `theme_textfield` copy it to your `template.php` and rename to `yourtheme_textfield` its look like this:

```
function theme_textfield($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'text';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value', 'size', 'maxlength'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-text'));

  $extra = '';
  if ($element['#autocomplete_path'] && drupal_valid_path($element['#autocomplete_path'])) {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.autocomplete');
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-autocomplete';

    $attributes = array();
    $attributes['type'] = 'hidden';
    $attributes['id'] = $element['#attributes']['id'] . '-autocomplete';
    $attributes['value'] = url($element['#autocomplete_path'], array('absolute' => TRUE));
    $attributes['disabled'] = 'disabled';
    $attributes['class'][] = 'autocomplete';
    $extra = '<input' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
  }

  $output = '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';


  //This will add div element with class SOME_CLASS
  //================================
  $output = '<div class="SOME_CLASS">' . $output . '</div>';
  //=====================


  return $output . $extra;
}
```

As you can see you can do what you want. Here for example i added `<div class="SOME_CLASS"><input></input></div>`.

If you need this class for different form elements find  `theme_form_element($variables)` in `form.inc` copy it to your template.php and rename to `yourtheme_form_element` and do whatever you want. This works for `drupal7`.