# How add additional css classes to description field in webform component?

Tags: webforms, theming

I want to add additional CSS classes to webform component description field.

in default mode, this item is wrapped inside a div element with "description" class like below:

```
<div class="description">here is description text</div>
```

Now I want to add extra CSS classes beside description.

How can I do this? via a module and form alter operation or via theme functions hook?

Please guide me.

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68453/how-to-add-a-class-div-on-drupal-7-webform-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by using jquery on ready do this something like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         jQuery('#YOUR_FORM_ID .description').addClass('new-desc-class');
});
```

Comment: I know this solution but it is not useful when javascript is disabled on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for [webform classe](https://drupal.org/project/webform-classes)s module:

> A simple, small add-in that adds an editable class against each webform component to the webforms module.

Then, in your CSS use `.class-on-form-element .description` instead of `.class-on-description` - one word more, but works just as well.

Comment: Does it add class to description too ?

Comment: @Mehrdad201 Not sure what description is, in Form API terms. If `#description` then no, as Drupal can't do it in the first place. No hooks / attributes for it. For code solution, see how I hacked it [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/94561/16495) and [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/94555/16495). Code from these answers + code from module above will give you a kickstart. **Or simply add class to element and then in css use `.element's class .description`**

Comment: Dear @Mołot I tested it, It doesn't add the class description, it is add the class to the element. I am studying your mentioned URLs. but I want to add only some extra CSS to the description element and I think there must be a solution for it without a large number of code lines. I am still searching. I think description must have #prefix and #suffix and I want to find how can I change it's rendering style.